# Using static variables

Tags: coldfusion, static, cfml, coldbox

I'm using the ColdBox framework in ColdFusion. I would like to know how to use static variables in a function. Can anyone explain how, or suggest an alternative to the "static" concept.

Comment: 'static variable' is a contradiction in terms... do you mean a constant?

Comment: There's no static.  There's Application scope though, just sticks whatever static you want there and use it from there throughout

Comment: Coldfusion does not use static variables.  What are you trying to accomplish with this variable?

Comment: In the context of ColdFusion, your question doesn't make much sense. Can you include some code (or pseudo-code) of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I suppose you could make a CFC and disable the setter?

Comment: Similar Question and Answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288302/what-is-the-equivalent-of-static-methods-in-coldfusion

Comment: Similar Question and Answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288302/what-is-the-equivalent-of-static-methods-in-coldfusion

Comment: Similar Question and Answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288302/what-is-the-equivalent-of-static-methods-in-coldfusion

Answer (score 4):

Using a component's metadata we can mimic static variable behavior:

- [Using Metadata To Add Static Variables to ColdFusion Components](http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2011/02/using-metadata-to-add-static-variables.html)
- [ColdFusion Domain Objects, Static Methods & a Common API](http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2010/01/06/coldfusion-domain-objects-static-methods-a-common-api)